# Time efficient way to pass pointer to a Macro

Tags: c++, c, macros

Most of my code involves passing address of a memory location to several macros which does the required job.

Could you please explain which is the best way to pass the address in terms of a time efficiency.

Sample code:

```
#define FILL_VAL(ptr  /* uint8_t* */  )    \
        do                                 \
        {                                  \
           /* Macro which does the job */  \
                                           \
        }while(0);

uint8_t *buf = malloc(100);
uint16_t buf_index = 0;

//Method 1:

FILL_VAL(&buf[buf_index])

//Method 2:
FILL_VAL( buf + buf_index)
```

Comment: Both methods are Identical. It should generate the same assembly.

Comment: Have you compared the assembly code produced for the two methods?

Comment: You ask for the best way... It's nearly always to avoid macros and use functions instead. Then let the compiler inline when it makes sense.

Comment: Possible difference is if you don't use `ptr` with `(ptr)` and precedence issue (as `*ptr`).

Answer (score 0):

Macros / defines are just text substitutions. And as such, they can not directly influence "time/space/whatever efficiency" of the target program.

So basically your question must be rephrased as "will my compiler generate same code for (similar) expressions containing `buf + buf_index` and `&buf[buf_index]`"?

Actually, only live experiments can proof this, but it's a very reasonable guess that the generated code will be the same.

Comment: Macros are preprocessor token substitutions, not text substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

- In C++ &buf[buf_index] is preferred.
- In C buf + buf_index is normal.

Why??

In C, it's part of the definition of the idiom. "Why say say things with more words than possible?". Say it in the shortest possible way, it makes it easier to understand and harder to type wrong.

C++ Introduced containers. These are data structures that "look" like something they are not. To illustrate this, consider a piece of code that uses a fixed-size C-array.

```
int my_vec[FIXED_SIZE]; // create elements
FILL_VAL(&my_vec);
```

Later you want to switch to a variable size array.

```
std::vector<int> my_vec(FIXED_SIZE); // create a container for elements
FILL_VAL(&my_vec); // << WRONG!!!
```

Now your "FILL_VAL" macro does the wrong thing. it will write over the actual vector, almost certainly creating a bad pointer, and eventually memory corruption. This is why very early in the use of C++ most programmers switched to this style.

```
std::vector<int> my_vec(FIXED_SIZE); // create a container for elements
FILL_VAL(&my_vec[0]); // << Works for c-array and vector!
```

As for which is faster, they express exactly the same thing. Compilers will treat these as exactly the same thing. It is not unusual for compilers to start with a pass that swaps equivalent code for a single standard representation. This way the code generation pass can be simpler.